# how to approach such an assigment: Spring Project, H2 database, simple model (String name, BigDecimal price)

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

how would you approach problem of simple app, allowing users to summarise/calculate average of price values of inventory stored? MVC model, Spring, H2. Do I need Hibernate to achieve that? How to access fields of particular items stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement to use H2? If no, just 'read' the inventory and calculate on the fly. Build the minimal solution.

If yes, I personally prefer to go with Spring Boot / Spring Data / Hibernate as this is widely used and better to maintain than a self-build solution. You could get the information with a custom query at the repository - something like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT AVG(price) FROM product")
public Double getAveragePrice();
```

With https://bootify.io you can setup your Spring Boot app with the database model, and can add the custom logic on top.

Comment: But how to get access to particular Entity fields instead to whole json, without Hibernate? And with Hibernate, does it always require Java Configuration, like this: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring p 4.1?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your first question right - but without Hibernate you could access a database directly via JDBC, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/h2_database/h2_database_jdbc_connection.htm. The second link is relevant for plain Spring, but with Spring Boot there is very little Hibernate configuration - more like https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Thomas, for example: entity contains articles: id 1, article1, price: 1, id 2, article2, price: 2, I want to be able to return price summary = 1 + 2  in my Cotroller Entity

Comment: That's what I'm trying to point at in the original answer, use AVG or SUM query. Explained here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query